# htaccess - create a symbolic link from folders to html files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to create a **symbolic link** from **folders** to **html** files. So basically I want e.g. `localhost/about` to link on `localhost/about.html` without changing the URL. As I have multiple sites I just want a single rule for this. This is what I have so far:

```
Options -Indexes 
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(?:about|product)(\/)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ $1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following rule (if you want `html` pages, why are you using `.php` in your `RewriteRule`?):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d     # or RewriteCond $1 !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f # or RewriteCond $1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

Comment: Indeed this is working. But I really would like to support `localhost/about/`as well.

Comment: @kwoxer Is `about` an actual directory on your system? If not, replace `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` in my code with `$1`

Comment: No it's a symbolic one, or however this is called. It does not exists. I just want to use it as URL in my case. And replacing does not work for me =/

Comment: It should be very simple like a `(\/)` but I cannot get it to work for me. Any idea?